# @SQSListen results in an exception and not working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I've a very simple Spring cloud aws project. I'm using Java 11. 
here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.arf</groupId>
    <artifactId>testsqs-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testsqs-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Config class:

```
package com.demo.arf.testsqsboot;

import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
//import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
//import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
//import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder;

@Configuration
public class SQSConfig {

    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate() {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync());
    }

    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQS);
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

the controller class which send/receive message:

```
package com.demo.arf.testsqsboot.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SQSController {
    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQSController.class);
    @GetMapping("/send-sqs-message")
    public String sendMessage() {
        String sqsEndPoint= "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1234567879/my_queue";
        queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(sqsEndPoint, MessageBuilder.withPayload("hello from Spring Boot").build());
        return "Hello SQS";
    }

    @SqsListener("my_queue")
    public void getMessage(String message) {
      LOG.info(" *********** Message from SQS Queue - "+message);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9001
cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: us-east-1
      auto: false
    credentials:
      access-key: "asdmnasdn"
      secret-key: "sfkjsdjksdkj"
    end-point:
      uri: https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1234567879/my_queue
```

I can get the send working fine. but when I add the listener, I get the following error during startup and listener does not receive messages:

```
2020-03-15 01:02:00.677  INFO 15423 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3853 ms
2020-03-15 01:02:01.109  INFO 15423 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
**WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils (file:/Users/arf/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.415/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathContext.getDTMManager()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-03-15 01:02:01.749  WARN 15423 --- [           main]**
s.c.a.m.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Ignoring queue with name 'my_queue': The queue does not exist.; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; Request ID: 62821505-3f34-5434-a6ee)
2020-03-15 01:02:01.749  INFO 15423 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
```

Also, one basic question. How does the @SQSListener know where to find the aws account info and sqs uri?

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work with the following change in config class. However, I wonder, how most of the sample programs online without this code(which construct AmazonSQSAsync with withEndpointConfiguration) is working.

````
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQS);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS(AWSCredentialsProvider credentials) {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentials)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(localStackSqsUrl, awsRegion))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        return new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials("local", "stack")));
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.
- First NEVER store your AK/SK in a property or yml file like that.  I can tell those are fake values, but you'll always want to pull these from ~/.aws/credentials or instance metadata.  The AWS clients like AmazonSqSAsyncClientBuilder will do automatically if you just call .standard().  No need for the credential provider.
- Second, same with region
- Third, I believe @SqsListener will use the ContainerFactory bean you defined earlier, at least that's how the @JmsListener works.
- The error message you received was that your queue name was not found in your account in your selected region.  You told it us-east-1, but in your send code you specified us-east-2.  My guess based on your post is that your queue is in us-east-2 since your question came up about @SqsListener, not the queueMessagingTemplate.

Comment: I've tested this with both AWS and localstack. In both case I made sure the queue existed.How ever I didn't have the AWS profile setup locally(~/.aws...)
On the Listener, both SQSListener and JmsListener work the same way I guess. But how does the listener know which queue? especially I've multiple queues. I'm not providing any queue names while constructing the factory.

Comment: but you're providing the queue name in the @SQSListener annotation...

Comment: I had some time to basically replicate what you are doing.  Mine worked as long as I used the Queue URL in the annotation

Comment: Queue URL in which annotation? I thought the @SQSListner takes queue name not the full URI. My issue was with Listener.

Comment: Hi Sid - The Queue URL goes on the @SQSListener annotation.  The docs say it will take a logical name (from CloudFormation), URL, or physical name.  I put some demo code out at https://github.com/kennyk65/spring-teaching-demos/tree/master/spring-sqs-demo.  Looks like your queue name is correct, but region is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Yes the queue name goes in the SQSListner. My question was for how does the system knows what I’m trying to do is treating locally.  I’ve completed the implementation. I’ve two profiles one for localstack the other for aws. localstack profile I inject the url of the localstack in the config. for aws, spring picks it up from environment.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I thought you wanted to know 1) why you were getting an error on startup 2) why did your listener not receive messages 3) how does the @SQSListener know where to find the aws account info and sqs uri and 4) how does the listener know which queue.  I'm afraid I didn't follow the "what I'm trying to do is treating locally" phrase.